# IQueryable<object> LINQ Expression threw 'System.Object' to type 'Anonymous type'

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I wrote linq query to get data and store in `IQueryable<object>`. After that I want to perform Linq Expression to remove some null data.

```
  IQueryable<object> employees;

    select new
         {
              temp.EMP_NO,
              personal.EMP_NAME,
              hptrx.TRX_CD,
              trx.TRX_DESC,
              CURRENT_MONTH = hptrx.AMOUNT,
              PREVIOUS_MONTH = db.HPTRXes.Where(x => x.COMP_CD == temp.COMP_CD && x.EMP_NO == temp.EMP_NO && 
                               x.TRX_CD == hptrx.TRX_CD && x.P_MTH == previousMonth && x.P_YEAR == 
                               previousYear && x.P_PERIOD == record.P_PERIOD).Select(x => x.AMOUNT).FirstOrDefault()
         });
```

Below code will be executed to filter out PREVIOUS_MONTH contains null.

```
 var propertyPreviousMonth = "PREVIOUS_MONTH";
 var sourceType = typeof(object);
 var underlyingType = employees.First().GetType();
 var propertyType = underlyingType.GetProperty(propertyPreviousMonth).PropertyType;
 var param = Expression.Parameter(sourceType);

 var left = Expression.Property(
      Expression.Convert(param, underlyingType), propertyPreviousMonth
 );
 Expression right = Expression.Constant(null);
 Expression e1 = Expression.NotEqual(left, right);
 var lambda = Expression.Lambda(e1, param);

 var expr = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where", new Type[] { sourceType },
     employees.Expression, lambda
 );
 employees = employees.Provider.CreateQuery<object>(expr);
```

However, I'm getting below error when call `employees.Count()`

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Object' to type 'Anonymous type'. LINQ
>   to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: Looks like the `PREVIOUS_MONTH` isn't an `object`, What is it?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen `PREVIOUS_MONTH` is a property of object. I want to remove all the objects where `PREVIOUS_MONTH == NULL`

Comment: What about filtering the result with  `employees = employees.Where(e => e.PREVIOUS_MONTH  != null);` I think you won't need expression trees to filter out known columns/properties.

Comment: I cant filter like that since its an object and the properties will be resolved on runtime. Thats the reason i'm trying to use LINQ Expression

Comment: Well then employees is null

Comment: What about storing the query of `PREVIOUS_MONTH` into a `let preMonth = db.HPTRXes.Where(x => x.C......)` and then check `where preMonth != null` in your query? See my answer. (just a suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, you could try:

```
let prevMonth = db.HPTRXes.Where(x => x.COMP_CD == temp.COMP_CD && x.EMP_NO == temp.EMP_NO && 
                           x.TRX_CD == hptrx.TRX_CD && x.P_MTH == previousMonth && x.P_YEAR == 
                           previousYear && x.P_PERIOD == record.P_PERIOD).FirstOrDefault()
where prevMonth != null
select new
     {
          temp.EMP_NO,
          personal.EMP_NAME,
          hptrx.TRX_CD,
          trx.TRX_DESC,
          CURRENT_MONTH = hptrx.AMOUNT,
          PREVIOUS_MONTH = prevMonth.AMOUNT
     });
```

Comment: can I achieve it using linq expression like above, by any chance ?

Comment: You should try it, I can't test it here... I think the most important thing is that you do a FirstOrDefault on the row instead of the field. If Amount is a number, you'll get 0 as default. (and not null)

Comment: it has performance issue. The `where prevMonth != null` makes the query loads in 6sec. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.